# opencart cookies problem - how to fix?

Tags: php, c++

i have 2 stores here : oc v1.4.9.3

```
1) tsubamecorp.com/singapore/
2) tsubamecorp.com/malaysia/
```

The problem is when you login to `tsubamecorp.com/singapore/admin` everything is work fine.

The url after login look something like this

```
tsubamecorp.com/singapore/admin/index.php?route=common/home&token=827bcf36d9c167581620f377417e8774
```

but when you change the folder from `singapore` to `malaysia` in url

```
tsubamecorp.com/malaysia/admin/index.php?route=common/home&token=827bcf36d9c167581620f377417e8774
```

you can login without put username or pass in login page for malaysia store!!!

This only happen when you try in same browser.

Any solutions??

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the default behaviour of OpenCart (as explained by Zappo) you should set up a new host name for each shop instead. You'll have to register two separate DNS names and then access your shops as follows...

```
malaysia.tsubamecorp.com/admin/index.php
singapore.tsubamecorp.com/admin/index.php
```

You can still run with a single installation of OpenCart and a single database. This post may help you understand this configuration better...

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=21411

Answer (score 0):

I think this will only occur when you change the name and refresh. I guess when you log out and try to login again it will no work.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. My answer wouldnt be that helpfull. I have to think about your issue but my first thought would be that the cookies are on the same domain and thats where it will check for.

Comment: no.. it still can be login if you login from malaysia store..you just need to change the folder in url to singapore..thats all.. you will automatically can access admin page for singapore without login..

Answer (score 0):

That's default OpenCart behaviour...
I also think Jerome is correct. The cookies are in the same domain, so OpenCart thinks you're still logged-in.

HOWEVER, I don't see your problem...
If someone is able to get that cookie set, he or she already logged in...
(e.g. This can not happen when someone did not log in)